# Hi, How can I path plan a robot in ROS+gazebo using indoor GPS and odometry data?

Tags: navigation, odometry, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, How can I path plan a robot in ROS+gazebo using indoor GPS and odometry data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247018/hi,-how-can-i-path-plan-a-robot-in-ros+gazebo-using-indoor-gps-and-odometry-data?/) by [manju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27548/manju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) to fuse the indoor GPS data with the odometry, and a package like [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) or [moveit!](http://moveit.ros.org/) to do the path planning and motion planning.

May I ask how you are obtaining GPS indoors? Or is that part of your question?

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27548/manju/) on 2016-11-02**:
I am using infrared beacons to get the coordinates of the robot. It has got a ROS package and able to show the x,y,z coordinates